# Direction at which to look while praying

Tags: salat, fiqh, kaabah

During the obligatory and non-obligatory prayers (many) muslims look or focus at the point of prostration. Is there a specific reason for this ?

Are there any angles at which the worshipper can not look, less they invalidate their prayers ?

For those praying in the courtyard of the Ka'ba, is there a benefit from looking at the Ka'ba while praying, or this not recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the point of prostration is done to avoid drifting your mind to other things while praying.

There are many things you should do for a proper prayer:
* Cleansing yourself
* Focusing on the prayer
    - This would include avoiding laughter, or signaling people to answer them
        * To notify someone of something during the prayer you should say: "Allhu akbar" (i.e. if the Imam counted an improper numbers of Rikahas)
* Reading the Quran in a proper way
* Doing the proper actions

As for looking at the Ka'ba, I am not sure.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about this site. Also take your time to elaborate your answer to make it more useful see [answer]. Also what is your evidence for saying "Allahu akbar" instead of "subhan Allah" if the Imam makes a mistake in prayer. And of course one should try his best to face the Ka'aba while praying as one is asked to pray in the direction of it!